# SUSE "There is no device mounted at '/' during resize operation

Tags: partition, sles

I've got a problem with resizing of space in `/dev/sda2` for my SUSE system.
I've increased space on my virtual machine and booted under SUSE live CD, after I choose `/dev/sda2` and selected resize (maximum size). But when I trying proceed I get following error:

> - There is no device mounted at '/'

[image: screen of error]

Answer (score 1):

I've found another solution for this problem. 
I've used Gparted unility instead of partitioner and perform resize operation via Gparted.